# problema de javascript con el undefined

Tags: javascript

primero antes que todo buenas tardes y quisiera decir de un problema que tengo con javascript estaba practicando y me salio un resultado no esperado me ponía undefined en vez del resultado valga la redundancia el problema si no mas me equivoco (ya que no me dice donde esta el error ya que me supongo que me esta mal interpretando mis indicaciones) es con el parámetro e intentado quitárselo pero igual mente obtengo el mismo resultado también e intentado pues en vez de poner la variable en la llamada de la función en vez de eso poner directamente la palabra que quiero que me diga que tipo de dato es pero obtengo el mismo resultado.

aquí esta el código.

```
let palabra="hola mundo";

function analizador(palabra_parametro) {
if (typeof palabra_parametro===String) {
    document.write(palabra_parametro.length);      
} else if(typeof palabra_parametro===Number){
    document.write(palabra_parametro);
}   
}

document.write(analizador(palabra));
```

el objetivo de este programa por si no a quedado claro es que me haga algo diferente el programa por cada tipo de diferente de dato que sea la variable

Answer (score 1):

`typeof` devuelve una cadena

```js
let palabra="hola mundo";

function analizador(palabra_parametro) {
if (typeof palabra_parametro==='string') {
    document.write(palabra_parametro.length);      
} else if(typeof palabra_parametro==='number'){
    document.write(palabra_parametro);
}   
}

analizador(palabra)
```

Podrías usar un `switch` para que el código se vea más claro

```js
let palabra="hola mundo";

function analizador(palabra_parametro) {

    switch(typeof palabra_parametro){
     
      case 'string':
          document.write(palabra_parametro.length); 
      break;

      case 'number':
          document.write(palabra_parametro); 
      break;
    
    }
}

analizador(palabra)
```

Answer (score 1):

Piensa en la función `document.write`,  la cual recibe un valor como parámetro a escribir en el documento, ahora, debemos saber que una función puede o no retornar un valor (eso lo decides tú).

Por ejemplo:

```
//Esta función NO retorna un valor (de manera explícita)
function test(){
    var suma = 5 + 7;
}
```

Si ejecutamos el valor anterior, entonces, el valor de retorno será `undefined`.

Otro ejemplo:

```
//Esta si tiene valor de retorno
function test2(){
    var suma = 8 + 6;
    return suma;
}
```

Si está función se ejecuta por ejemplo como argumento de `document.write`, es lo mismo a `document.write(14)`.

Tu función:

```
let palabra="hola mundo";

function analizador(palabra_parametro) {
    if (typeof palabra_parametro===String) {
        document.write(palabra_parametro.length);      
    } else if(typeof palabra_parametro===Number){
        document.write(palabra_parametro);
    }   
}
```

Tu función debe devolver un resultado para ser escrito por `document.write`, pero eso no es todo, la condición: `typeof palabra_parametro===String` siempre se evaluará a `false` al igual que la siguiente condición, esto debido a que `typeof` devuelve un valor de tipo String ("string"), entonces la expresión a evaluar debe quedar así:

```
if(typeof palabra_parametro === "string"){ }
```

O bien, no devolver nada y escribir los datos dentro de la función (tu haces ambas cosas), en este caso solo debes ejecutar tu función solamente:

```
analizador(palabra);
```

Tu función se encargará de escribir en el documento lo que se tenga que escribir según las instrucciones que tenga.

Espero haber sido claro.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que comparar con una cadena
eso es lo que devuelve la funcion typeof
y cuando llamas a la funcion no es necesario que esté dentro de un document.write
ya que te retornaría un undefined al invocar dos document.write

```js
let palabra = "hola mundo";

        function analizador(palabra_parametro) {
            if (typeof palabra_parametro === "string") {
                document.write(palabra_parametro.length);
            } else if (typeof palabra_parametro === "number") {
                document.write(palabra_parametro);
            }
        }

        analizador(palabra);
```